# I have 2 columns, how I can fill one of them based on the other one?

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 columns, how I can fill one of them based on the other one?

if  `col2` was non_null make the `col1`==`col2` and keep `col1` everywhere:

```
col1     col2
null       'us'
'us'       null
'us'       null 
null       'us'
null       'us'
null       null
```

output

```
col1     col2
'us'       'us'
'us'       null
'us'       null 
'us'       'us'
'us'       'us'
null       null
```

Comment: and how is pyspark related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyspark.sql.functions.`coalesce(*cols)`: Returns the first column that is not null.

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([
    (None, 'us'),
    ('us', None),
    (None, 'us'),
    (None, None),
], ['col1', 'col2'])

data.withColumn('col1', coalesce(col('col1'), col('col2'))).show(10)
# +----+----+
# |col1|col2|
# +----+----+
# |  us|  us|
# |  us|null|
# |  us|  us|
# |null|null|
# +----+----+
```